# Deep linking - Fetch data when app installed from play store

Tags: java, android, deep-linking

How can we get data for the below situations:

1) Click on deep linking url.

2) That app is not installed in a device. So, It redirects to the play store.

3) Then we install app from the play store.

4) We want data when we open the application that is installed from the play store.

How can we get data in application when it comes from play store?

Comment: did you use firebase deep linking to create the url?

Comment: No, I do not use firebase deep linking

Answer (score 2):

you can use firebase dynamic URLs here is the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links)

it will give you everything that you needed.

Here is the code snippet:

Below this how it works.

https://domain/?link=your_deep_link&apn=package_name[&amv=minimum_version][&ad=1][&al=android_link][&afl=fallback_link]

Here's the example of the link after filling in the parameters.

https://example.app.goo.gl/?link=https://www.example.com/someresource&apn=com.example.android&amv=3&al=exampleapp://someresource&ibi=com.example.ios&isi=1234567&ius=exampleapp

you can also shorten the link directly at Firebase console.

Inside Activity, you can call AppInvite.AppInviteApi.getInvitation(mGoogleApiClient, this, false) to retrieve link information.

More information can be found here https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/

Comment: Can you please share the sample code for our reference?

Comment: @RonakGadhia, I have updated my answer please have a look

Comment: I have integrated firebase deep linking. But I get "PendingDynamicLinkData" null in success callback of FirebaseDynamicLinks. Can you please let us know your views?